# Triggering Multiple CSS Events

Tags: html, css, events, css-transitions

I have a List Item that on hover, changes its `BG` color and also makes the border right grow out from `0-7px`. Within the list item there is a label for a radio input that is toggling content off and on when clicked.  When the border grows, the label gets pushed over.

Is it possible to specify that on hover attributes `X` and Y happen to the list item, while triggering another `css` event to change the `z-index` of the label?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to hover over one element and this trigger an action on an adjacent element, just use plus sign. For example,

```
.hoverable:hover + .actionable {
```

Check out this codepen for a simple working example: http://codepen.io/Joi/pen/VKZqAX

Comment: But is it possible to have two different effects to those individual pieces?

Comment: Yes, you just have to have two separate rules (basically a rule each element type). I modified the codepen alittle bit so you can see how I can change both the div I'm hovering over and another one.